# I want to make a function that create a new task for a specific user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models in relation a User model and a Task model each user have inside an empty task array and I want a function that get the user by email and push a new task to the users task array I tried a lot but I don't made that function to work so I need some help here is my code.

User model:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
//connecting mongoose to mongoDB
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://tudor:tudor@cluster0.gbojb.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });

const { Post } = require("./PostModel")

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: [5, 'The password should have more then 5 characters']
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: [300, 'Description should have less then 300 characters']
    },
    tasks: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "task"
    }]
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);


exports.User = User
```

task model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let TaskSchema = new Schema({
    content: String,
    owner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", TaskSchema)
```

And here I want to make the function :

```
const createNewTask = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userEmail = req.params.id;
}
```

Comment: what are you using for authentication ?

Comment: i don't have one for the moment

Comment: but i am getting the user by the email the problem is I don't know how to create a new task for the user I get

Comment: I see okay I'll write the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how your function will work:

```
const createNewTask = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userEmail = req.params.id;
    
    // find user first by email
    const userData = await User.findOne({email: userEmail});
    // add check here if user exist or not (not writing it for now)

   // now create task by extract task payload (assuming you have detail in body)
   const taskData = await Task.create({
       content: req.body.content,
       owner: userData._id,
   });

   // now push task id in user
   await User.updateOne({
      email: userEmail
   }, {
     $push: {tasks: taskData._id},
   });
 
}
```

There can be some errors since didn't tested it but you get the idea how to do it.

Comment: post them down here

Comment: i try to send with postmen on body {"content":"test"} and I am getting ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot POST /create/task/testemail@yahoo.com</pre>
</body>

</html>``` inside postman

Comment: and inside terminal i get ```(node:2257) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.```

Comment: change your route to something like `create/task` and send email in body not in params or url encode your email first

Comment: ```{"content": "buna",
    "email": "testemail@yahoo.com"
}``` thats my body and I am still getting errors

Comment: Dude change the route, don't send email in url like /create/task/testemail@yahoo.com just send /create/task and email in body

Comment: yeah i made that

Comment: post your route and controller